# Custom javascript function showing as Not defined when calling from server side asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Ive a custom javascript function at the end of the page like this

```
........
...
<script  language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function myfunction(msg)
{
...
...
alert(msg);
}
</script>
</body>
```

And am calling this function from a button event like this

```
Dim csType As Type = Me.GetType
Dim sName As String = "AlertScript"
Dim sText As String
sText = String.Format("<script language='javascript'>myfunction('mymessage : {0}');</script>", msg)
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, sName, sText)
```

But in firebug it says myfunction is not defined.

What I did wrong

At the same time if I specify **alert** instead of myfunction it works and showing an alert box.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that your function is not loaded yet, try defining and accessing using window

window.myfunction

and calling it the same way

Comment: Also i see that you define myfunction at the end of the page so it will be definded after the call

Comment: basically you are trying to call the function before its defined. alert() is always defined. Try putting your call after the defenition. If you cant do that there is a "hacky" way, simply put your call inside setTimeout(function(){ myfunction(data);},0)

Comment: I tried before the page load also. Still it showing not defined. Anyway let me try the hacky way

Comment: not the page load, browser will run the js tags as they come. first come first serve. as long as your call will appear in page source before the defenition it will always fail to run